# Bootstrap - responsiveness

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

With Bootstrap grid system,

in container-large-desktop smaller values than 1200px getting one under the other. like this:

[image]

But I want them to floating side by side and getting smaller - like this until 760px:

[image]

Also like in halfbrick web site images in middle of the screen getting smaller with scale response.

Is there any way to manage it with bootstrap or should it implement with JS by myself?

Comment: This is something that CSS media-queries can be used for. In fact, Bootstrap provide responsive versions of their CSS

Comment: This is Built in Bootstrap feature, if you use the correct classes. Are you asking about which classes to add in order to achieve this layout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this can be done with Bootstrap alone, try the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

This way on large devices you will have three columns, and when you go below 768px they will stack one on top of the other. For different sizes you can use `xs`, `md` and `lg` instead, for `<768px`, `>992px` and `>1200px` respectively.

For the responsive images you can use:

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

And they will automatically resize according to their container size.

Take a look at the **[Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)**, all of this is pretty well explained there.

Comment: Wow! Almost i was moving to some other frameworks. Container-fluid and col-ms-4 keywords that i was missing. Thank you very much! Also thanks @aurbano , bootply is also good system to communicate, I will use it!